# Update Image using Laravel 8 Livewire component

Tags: jquery, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, php-8

I want to update Image in my Laravel 8 project with Livewire and I'm using Bootstarp as css framework. I want to use Type hinting for file editing purpose but after retrieving from the database cannot able to preview in blade component modal. I retrieved all the data from the Database and I've checked that on the Network Tab while inspecting and I've already showed Title and Description but cannot able to show Images.

This is my code for blade component...

```
<div wire:ignore.self class="modal inmodal in" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Service Edit Form</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; margin: 10px 10px 0 0;">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                            <div class="ibox-title">
                                <h5>NB: <small>Please fill the field with (<span style="color: red;">*</span>) symbol.</small></h5>
                                <div class="ibox-tools">
                                    <a class="collapse-link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ibox-content">
                                <form wire:submit.prevent="update()" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="title">
                                            Service Title <span style="color: red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Service Title" wire:model.lazy="editing.title">
                                            @error('title') <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="description">
                                            Description <span style="color: red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10" wire:ignore>
                                            <textarea id="edit-description" name="description" wire:model.lazy="editing.description">{{ $description }}</textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                                            @error('description') <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="logo_img_path">
                                            Icon Image <span style="color: red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="file" id="logo_img_path" name="logo_img_path" wire:model="editing.logo_img_path"/>
                                            @error('logo_img_path') <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                                            <br>
                                            @if($logo_img_path)
                                                <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/services'.$logo_img_path) }}" />
                                            @else
                                                <img class="img-lg img-rounded" src="{{ $this->logoImageUrl() }}" alt="Service Logo Image">
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="bg_img_path">
                                            Background Image <span style="color: red;">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <input type="file" id="bg_img_path" name="bg_img_path" wire:model="editing.bg_img_path"/>
                                            @error('bg_img_path') <small style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</small> @enderror
                                            <br>
                                            @if($bg_img_path)
                                                <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/services'.$bg_img_path) }}" />
                                            @else
                                                <img class="img-lg img-rounded" src="{{ $this->bgImageUrl() }}" alt="Service Logo Image">
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" type="submit">Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my code for edit and update:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Service;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use Livewire\Component;
use Auth;

class ServiceComponent extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    // public $isOpen = false;

    public $title;
    public $description;
    public $logo_img_path;
    public $bg_img_path;

    public Service $editing;

    protected $rules = [
        'editing.title' => 'required|unique:services,title',
        'editing.description' => 'required',
        'editing.logo_img_path' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,svg,jpg,gif',
        'editing.bg_img_path' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,svg,jpg,gif',
    ];

    public function resetInputFields()
    {
        $this->title = "";
        $this->description = "";
        $this->logo_img_path = "";
        $this->bg_img_path = "";
    }

    public function mount()
    {

    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.service-component',['services'=>Service::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()])->layout('admin.adminbase');
    }

    // public function create()
    // {
    //     $this->resetInputFields();
    //     $this->openModal();
    // }

    // public function openModal()
    // {
    //     $this->isOpen = true;
    //     // Clean errors if were visible before
    //     $this->resetErrorBag();
    //     $this->resetValidation();
    // }

    // public function closeModal()
    // {
    //     $this->isOpen = false;
    // }

    public function updatedTitle()
    {
        $this->validate(['title' => 'unique:services,title']);
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'title' => 'required|unique:services,title',
            'description' => 'required',
            'logo_img_path' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,svg,jpg,gif',
            'bg_img_path' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,svg,jpg,gif',
        ]);

        $validatedData['logo_img_path'] = $this->logo_img_path->store("/",'services');
        $validatedData['bg_img_path'] = $this->bg_img_path->store("/",'services');
        $validatedData['created_by'] = Auth::user()->id;
        $validatedData['updated_by'] = Auth::user()->id;

        $company = Service::create($validatedData);
        // session()->flash('message', 'Service created successfully!');

        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->emit('storedData');
    }

    public function edit(Service $services)
    {
        //dd($services);
        $this->editing = $services;
        $this->emit('initSummernote', $this->editing->description);
        // $company = Company::findOrFail($id);
        // $this->company_id = $id;
        // $this->title = $company->title;
        // $this->openModal();
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate();
        // $this->emit('resetSummernote');
        dd($this->editing);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->company_id = $id;
        Company::find($id)->delete();
        session()->flash('message', 'Company deleted successfully.');
    }

    public function logoImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->logo_img_path
            ? Storage::disk('services')->url($this->logo_img_path)
            : 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5(strtolower(trim($this->title)));
    }

    public function bgImageUrl()
    {
        return $this->bg_img_path
            ? Storage::disk('services')->url($this->bg_img_path)
            : 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5(strtolower(trim($this->title)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are still looking for a solution here u go:

Livewire Components add :

```
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $image = '';

    public function submit(){
        $this->validate([
            'image' => 'required|max:1024', //1MB
        ]);

        // Execution doesn't reach here if validation fails.
       
        DB::transaction(function () {
          $ImageName = md5($this->image . 
          microtime()).'.'.$this->image->extension();
          $this->image->storeAs('public/images', $ImageName);
        });
    }
```

Now in the blade view add the preview for the image, which is showed immediately after begin uploaded (keep in mind that this is a tmp path+name used by livewire):

```
@if ($image)
<div class="space-y-1 text-center">
                    <div class="flex text-sm text-gray-600">
                        <img src="{{ $image->temporaryUrl() }}" class="h-64">
                    </div>
                </div>
@else
.... ur file upload form
@endif
```

Now to render the image u saved use the following as img path (remember to enable to storage link, check it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)) :

```
asset('storage/images/' . $model_name->image)
```